# Where can I find the ABI for PancakeSwap RouterV2?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, web3.py, python

Where can I get the PancakeSwap ABI?
I have a simple code, but I don't understand where to get ABI

```
pancakeaddr =  '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E'
abi = ?
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeaddr, abi=abi)
contract.decode_function_input(TxInput)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the ABI [here](https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e#code)

Oftentimes smart contracts are verified on block explorers.